# How to recibe message from java socket to kotlin client?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sockets

I have this socket in Java that has to receive and send messages to a Kotlin client. Java successfully receives the message from Kotlin, but when analyzing and transforming the message, I have to return it to Kotlin and save it in an .xml file. I am unable to return the message and I don't understand my error. please help.

I'm using android studio and java netbeans

Kotlin: sends message thru a button -> done
Java: successfully receives the message and analyzes it. -> done
java: If the message has errors, it sends a message with these errors. -> NO (with this errors I mean in the syntax, no java errors)
Kotlin: It receives the errors and saves them in an XML file. -> NO

I'm sending this 'errors' in a string format

java socket:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
        sjf.setVisible(true);

        logger.info("Starting server...");
        sjf.agregarLog("Iniciando servidor");

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
        logger.info("Server started on port {}", serverSocket.getLocalPort());

        while (true) {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            logger.info("Accepted connection from {}", clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
            sjf.agregarLog("Se acepto conexion");

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder messageBuilder = new StringBuilder(); // Usamos un StringBuilder para concatenar todas las
            // líneas
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { // Leer todas las líneas disponibles
                messageBuilder.append(line);
                messageBuilder.append("\n"); //
            }
            String message = messageBuilder.toString(); // Convertir el StringBuilder a una cadena

            logger.info("Received message from {}: {}", clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress(), message);
            peti = message;
            sjf.agregarLog(peti);

            // write json file
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(
                    "mypath/archivo.json");

            fileWriter.write(message);
            fileWriter.close();
            // analizar
            aux = false;
            lista = new Lista(); // reiniciar lista de errores
            analizarMensaje();

//send errors feedback !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStream, true);
            printWriter.println("Hello, Kotlin!");
            printWriter.close();

        }
```

and kotlin :

```
private inner class SendMessageTask : AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>() {

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String): Boolean {
        try {
            val socket = Socket("192.168.0.36", 8080)
            val writer = PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true)
            for (mensaje in params) { // Iterar sobre todas las líneas recibidas
                writer.println(mensaje) // Enviar cada línea al socket
            }

            writer.close()
            

            // Receive the message from the Java socket and save it to a text file
            val inputStream = socket.getInputStream()
            val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
            val message = bufferedReader.readLine()
            bufferedReader.close()

            val file = File("received_message.txt")
            val printWriter = PrintWriter(file)
            printWriter.println(message)
            printWriter.close()

            println("Received message saved to file: ${file.absolutePath}")
            socket.close()
            return true
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            return false
        }
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: Boolean) {
        if (!result) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error al enviar el mensaje", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send newline character at the end of your message from your Java socket. Just add "\n" at the end of it.

Comment: just changing that linea? like: 'printWriter.println("Hello, Kotlin!" + "\n");' it didn't workv :(

Comment: Yeah, I though that’s the problem. Sorry!